# I need my navigation bar to be transparent but only in home page. And white background in other pages

Tags: angular, angular6

I need my navigation bar to be transparent only in home page. And white bg navigation bar in other pages. I tried to do that in angular but it didn't work. Here are my codes:

navbar.component.html

```
<nav [class.transparent-bg]="isHomePage"></nav>
```

navbar.component.ts

```
isHomePage = function(){
        if(window.location.hash =='#/'){
            return true; 
        }else{
            return false; 
        }
     }
```

By doing this, navigation bar from all pages became transparent bg. pleas help.

Comment: in simple way you can put the id in navbar and oninti of home page using id you can set background as transparent and on the same way when you are routing to some other page you can set navbar background as white.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can you use Router to get the current routing url. For more information you can see angular documentation https://angular.io/guide/router

**Solution:**

nav.component.ts

```
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

constructor(private router: Router){}

isHomePage(){
    if(this.router.url == 'YOUR_HOME_URL'){
        return true; 
    }else{
        return false; 
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Add [ngClass]="{'transparent-bg': rla.isActive }" to navbar

```
<nav [ngClass]="{'transparent-bg': rla.isActive }"></nav>
```

In the nav-item

```
<li class="nav-item ">
        <a  #rla="routerLinkActive" routerLinkActive="active-route"
            routerLink="/home">Home</a>
</li>
```